# Does anyone remember “!” (Explanation point) being referred to as “bang” or “baseball bat”

Tags: unix

I’m a former programmer who programmed in Unix and C in the early eighties. We used to refer to the “!” (Explanation point) as “bang” or “baseball bat”. I could not find that in any dictionary on the web.  I worked at  bell labs in Homdel NJ. Anyone ever heard of this?  Just a little nostalgia

Comment: bang is common american slang https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark#:~:text=Slang%20and%20other%20names%20for%20the%20exclamation%20mark,-Now%20obsolete%2C%20the&text=In%20the%201950s%2C%20secretarial%20dictation,probably%20emerged%20from%20letterpress%20printing.

Comment: and see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62918/why-is-the-exclamation-mark-called-a-bang

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - although it is interesting since I was trained in about the same era - it is not a valid SO question.